How to remove rows of multiple .csv files
I am not currently certain of the best way to go about this, so if there are any suggestions regarding a more efficient way, I would appreciate it!
To start, here is some toy data:
data <- data.frame(
  "stim" = c("face", "object", " ", "pareidolia"),
  "RT" = c(23, 24, 22, 25),
  "Opac" = c(70, 60, 80, 65)
)

write.csv(data, "data.csv")

data <- data.frame(
  "stim" = c("face", "pareidolia", " ", "pareidolia"),
  "RT" = c(83, 24,52, 85),
  "Opac" = c(70, 87, 8, 6)
)

write.csv(data, "data.csv")

I am currently reading in multiple .csv files like so:
library("tidyverse")
base :: setwd("filepath")
files <- base::list.files(
  path = ("filepath"), 
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "*.csv"
)

I am then creating a list of dataframes with the .csv file contents and removing rows that correspond to blank cells in the stim column of each dataframe. Then, I am making filepaths from list names.
datalist <- lapply(files, read.csv)

with(datalist, subset(datalist, !("stim" == ""))) -> datalist

file_out <- paste0(names(datalist), ".csv")

Finally, I am attempting to write each dataframe in the list to it's own .csv file.
mapply(
  function(x, y) write_csv(x, y), 
  datalist, 
  file_out
)

The problem is that this code doesn't seem to work. It doesn't output any .csv file except for a single file titled simply ".csv," which when opened, I get an error stating that the file doesn't exist. Is there a better way to go about this process to acheive the desired results? Thank you so much.

Did you define file_out somewhere? It doesn't seem to be included in the question. And are you sure this line works:with(datalist, subset(datalist, !("stim" == ""))) -> datalist? I would expect you to need to do the filtering in a lapply as well. The with() part doesn't seem to be doing anything. If your sample you seem to be overring the same "data.csv" file so it will only one file will be created and it will contain data from the second data.frame since the first will be overwritten

The quotes around stim in !("stim" == "") are wrong. This is not at all the same use as when naming columns when you create the df's. Correct: !(stim == "") or simpler stim != ""

@MrFlick yes, so sorry- I forgot to copy that into the post. I have edited the post to include the file_out definition.

@RuiBarradas when I change the quotes around stim, it gives an error stating that the object is not found.

See my answer, I believe it answers to your comment.

@thefriendly_plague.doctor  The problem was NOT that there was no column in the various dataframes in datalist but rather that the structure of datalist had the dataframes embedded within individual unnamed list entries. You should have looped over datalist. Rui would have been correct in the situation where datalist had been a dataframe (which it was NOT), It was a list of dataframes, which is not a dataframe. You could have seen this is you had run str on datalist.

First make files to be processed.
data <- data.frame(
  "stim" = c("face", "object", " ", "pareidolia"),
  "RT" = c(23, 24, 22, 25),
  "Opac" = c(70, 60, 80, 65)
)

write.csv(data, "data1.csv")

data <- data.frame(
  "stim" = c("face", "pareidolia", " ", "pareidolia"),
  "RT" = c(83, 24,52, 85),
  "Opac" = c(70, 87, 8, 6)
)

write.csv(data, "data2.csv")

Now the question's problem.

get the full filenames with list.files;
for each filename, lapply an anonymous function to read the data, remove all unwanted spaces from column stim, subset the data.frame and rewrite it to disk.

files <- list.files(
  path = "~/Temp",
  pattern = "data.*\\.csv",
  full.names = TRUE
)

lapply(files,\(x) {
  df1 <- read.csv(x)
  df1$stim <- trimws(df1$stim)
  df1 <- subset(df1, stim != "")
  write.csv(df1, x, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
})

Now check that the files were correctly saved.
lapply(files, read.csv)
#> [[1]]
#>   X       stim RT Opac
#> 1 1       face 23   70
#> 2 2     object 24   60
#> 3 4 pareidolia 25   65
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   X       stim RT Opac
#> 1 1       face 83   70
#> 2 2 pareidolia 24   87
#> 3 4 pareidolia 85    6

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
